# How to overlay icons on top of footer of bootstrap 4 card?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have simple Bootstrap 4 card with footer that has some text and icon. Here is the code:

```
  <div class="card ">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer ">
  <a href="#" class=" "><i style=" font-size: 2.5em;" class="fab fa-facebook "></i></a>
    <span class="float-right" >some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I place fa icon code it expands the footer. What I want that the icon is simply overlayed on footer area (kind of floating on it) without disturbing the size of footer i.e the size of the footer to remain the same as if the icon code is not placed. There are multiple cards on page with same footer.

How to accomplish this ?

Comment: You can try setting the icon's position to absolute, like `<i class="fas fa-user" style="position: absolute">` but you can get some weird behavior. But just try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your icon element from the normal elements flow by set its parent to `position: relative` and the icon element to `position: absolute`. This way, your icons position depends on the footer and you can adjust the position e.g. with `top`.

If you have multiple icons, you can either adjust the position of every single icon or place them in a container `<div>` which then is set to `position: absolute` instead of the icons.

```css
.card-footer {
  position: relative;
}

.icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: -.35rem;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card ">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </div>
    <span class="float-right">some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works but if I place additional icons, they stack on top of each other kind of overwriting on each and unreadable.

Comment: In this case, put all your icons in an absolute positioned container. Updated my snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well there technically is multiple ways to achieve this.

Either the icon needs a set `position: absolute` attribute.

But you could also have a set height on your footer element `height: 300px` for example. But that might move your other content around (unsure if that is what you want).